# Vertex coordinates from General_polygon_2

Tags: c++, polygon, vertex, cgal

Explanations, pointers, or examples that show how to extract vertex coordinates from a `General_Polygon_2` would be greatly appreciated.

The use case is offsetting (Minkowski sum with a circle) a simple polygon.  Construction accuracy is not critical.  I can seem to construct the source polygon to supply to `approximated_offset_2` , but I have not been able to figure out, once the offset polygon has been constructed, how to extract vertices from the `General_polygon_2` that comes from the `outer_boundary()` method.

A reduced example code is below:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>

// CGAL includes
#include <CGAL/Cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_2.h>
#include <CGAL/approximated_offset_2.h>
#include <CGAL/offset_polygon_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Lazy_exact_nt.h>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>

// typedefs for CGAL items
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Polygon_2<Kernel> Polygon_2;
typedef CGAL::Point_2<Kernel> Point_2;
typedef CGAL::Gps_circle_segment_traits_2<Kernel> Gps_traits_2;
typedef Gps_traits_2::Polygon_with_holes_2 Offset_polygon_with_holes_2;
typedef CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Quotient<CGAL::MP_Float> > NT;

typedef struct {double x; double y;} vertex_2;

void init_regular_ngon_2(std::vector<vertex_2>& ngon_vertices, const double center_x, const double center_y, const double r)
{
  unsigned int i, num_subdiv;
  double theta;

  num_subdiv = ngon_vertices.size();

  for (i = 0; i < num_subdiv; i++)
  {
    theta = 2.0 * M_PI * (double)i / (double)num_subdiv;
    ngon_vertices[i].y = center_y + (r * sin(theta));
    ngon_vertices[i].x = center_x + (r * cos(theta));
  }
}

void ngon_2_to_CGAL_poly(const std::vector<vertex_2>& ngon_vertices, Polygon_2& dest_poly)
{
  unsigned int i;

  for (i = 0; i < ngon_vertices.size(); i++)
  {
    dest_poly.push_back(Point_2(ngon_vertices[i].x, ngon_vertices[i].y));
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<NT>::set_relative_precision_of_to_double(1E-8);

  Polygon_2 test_poly;
  Offset_polygon_with_holes_2 offset_poly;
  std::vector<vertex_2> ngon(8);

  init_regular_ngon_2(ngon, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0);
  ngon_2_to_CGAL_poly(ngon, test_poly);

  offset_poly = approximated_offset_2(test_poly, 0.85, 1E-5);
  printf("The offset polygon has %d verts and %d holes\n", offset_poly.outer_boundary().size(), offset_poly.number_of_holes());

  // How to obtain vertex coordinates comprising offset polygon boundary??  Goal is to to store these in a vector of vertex_2 for later manipulation.

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following should do the job:

```
typedef Gps_traits_2::General_polygon_2 General_polygon_2;
const General_polygon_2& outer_boundary = offset_poly.outer_boundary();
General_polygon_2::Curve_const_iterator cit=outer_boundary.curves_begin(),
                                        cit_end=outer_boundary.curves_end();

for(;cit!=cit_end;++cit)
{
  bool is_linear = cit->is_linear();
  std::cout << cit->source() << " " << cit->target() << "\n";  
}
```

The list of all member functions are given [here](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Arrangement_on_surface_2/classCGAL_1_1Arr__circle__segment__traits__2_1_1Curve__2.html).

Comment: Please know that your willingness to help with this "newbiesque" question is very much appreciated.  It says a lot about this software's community that such a basic question would get answered by a core developer, and without any dismissive or negative attitude.  Thank you, that was the push in the right direction I'd hoped for.

Answer (score 1):

`approximated_offset_2` returns a `Polygon_with_holes` with the  `outer_boundary()` you can get the `General_polygon_2`, but you can't iterate through its vertices only through its curves and then you can get the target and source of the curve, as sloriot mentioned. The target and source points are not `Kernel::Point_2` members so you can't use `=` operator, but you can get `target.x()` and `target.y()` which are its coordinates and are members of class `CoordNT` which is not a *double/float* number but 3 numbers `(alpha, beta, gamma)` and you can calculate the exact value from the equation **x = a+b * sqrt(c)**.

```
typedef Gps_traits_2::General_polygon_2 General_polygon_2;
const General_polygon_2& outer_boundary = offset_poly.outer_boundary();
General_polygon_2::Curve_const_iterator cit;

for(cit = outer_boundary.curves_begin();
            cit !=outer_boundary.curves_end();++cit){

        source = Point2((cit->source().x().alpha())+
                (cit->source().x().beta()*sqrt(cit->source().x().gamma())),
                (cit->source().y().alpha())+
                (cit->source().y().beta()*sqrt(cit->source().y().gamma())));

        target = Point2((cit->target().x().alpha())+
                (cit->target().x().beta()*sqrt(cit->target().x().gamma())),
                (cit->target().y().alpha())+
                (cit->target().y().beta()*sqrt(cit->target().y().gamma())));
```